# Can I have multiple Progressive Web Apps on my site?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My company has a very large site made up of lots of distinct sections, each maintained by their own team (e.g. browse pages vs checkout).

Does it make sense to build a separate Progressive Web App for each section, or do we need to unify our approach and build only a single Progressive Web App?

Answer (score 2):

Think about progressive web apps in the same way you think about native applications. Then think if makes sense to have separated applications and you'll get your answer.

Being specific with your question I think you distinguish between some kind of info pages and service pages you currently keep under the same domain. If this is so, be aware that progressive web apps are unique by origin (protocol + domain name + port) and need HTTPS enabled so keeping separated progressive web apps can incur in additional infrastructure costs.

Nevertheless, this does not mean the same teams you have now can not maintain different parts of the same application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving from a legacy website to progressive web apps (PWA), then I'd suggest you start small.  Build a serious but not mission-critical PWA that performs a single function and go through the development/deploy process of building a PWA with Service Workers (fast reload and offline), home page installation and push notifications.  This is no different than introducing any new technology to an organization (e.g, cloud, microservices, devops, et al).

A progressive web application is an application.  And that PWA can potentially be installed on the home screen of a smartphone.  I don't think you want users to have separate apps/icons on their home screens for your web "site".

Imo, your website should be a collection of microservices that are accessed via the web, not really a collection of applications.  This gives you much more flexibility and agility.   Combining microservices with PWA can be quite compelling for both content producers and users.